# Количество потоков в Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, tpl

Устанавливаю количество потоков в 10, но оно работает в три потока (трехядерный комп).

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, 
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
    () => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
    (i, loopState, threadId) =>
    {
        var cells = i.Split(';');
        var ip = cells[0];
        var login = cells[1];
        var pass = cells[2];
        try
        {
            using (var client = new SshClient(ip, login, pass))
            {
                client.Connect();
                var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 10000 + (uint)threadId, "ya.ru", 80);
                port.Start();
                client.AddForwardedPort(port);
                newList.Add(ip);
                port.Stop();
                client.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch 
        {

        }

        return threadId;
    },
    (threadId) => { }
```

Answer (score 4):

В Parallel.ForEach количество потоков задается максимальным, а реальное количество потоков зависит от доступных ресурсов. Если нужно точное количество потоков, то можно использовать PLINQ либо использовать собственное решение с помощью кастомного TaskScheduler, либо явного контроля с помощью WaitHandle.

Также не нужно забывать, что работа с сетью это так называемые "I/O bound потоки", поэтому лучше использовать такую асинхронность при условии, что используемая библиотека/класс это позволяет

Answer (score 1):

Насколько помню, у `Parallel.ForEach` довольно сложная логика, когда он сам подбирает наиболее оптимальное количество потоков для выполнения задачи.
А `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` определяет лишь максимально возможное количество потоков. По своему опыту знаю, что количество активных потоков довольно сильно плавает, увеличиваясь и уменьшаясь в зависимости от характеристик компьютера, решаемых параллельно задач и того, насколько они занимают ресурсы.

Хардкорный способ запустить сразу большое количество потоков - увеличить размер пула при старте приложения, например

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200);
Parallel.ForEach(...
```

Не буду говорить, что это хороший способ. Но тем не менее, мне когда такое решение помогло, когда надо было обрабатывать несколько сотен (или даже тысяч) параллельных потоков, выполняющих большие операции, связанные с вводом/выводом и сетевым взаимодействием.

Comment: Проверил. Все также

Comment: Увеличение размера пула не подойдет, т.е. Parallel.ForEach опирается на количество ядер и загруженность системы.

Comment: @andreycha `Parallel.ForEach` опирается на много критериев и факторов, и в том числе на размер пула. Говорю чисто из практического опыта, без увеличения пула, парраллельое выполнение начиналось с 2-3 потоков, увеличиваясь до нескольких сотен, увеличение размера пула же позволяло при старте получать сразу более тысячи параллельных потоков.  Определенно есть какие-то еще факторы, но я не разбирался детально в устройстве `Parallel.ForEach`, пока не было необходимости, а поделился лишь личным опытом =)

Comment: Пробовал таким образом задать максимальное количество потоков – Parallel.For его просто игнорирует (поставил 2, запустилось 12)

Comment: @Титан SetMinThreads - инициализирует пул потоков, определяя минимальное, а не максимальное количество потоков.

Для ограничения потоков в Parallel.ForEach необходимо использовать MaxDegreeOfParallelism.

Answer (score 1):

Если c `Parallel.ForEach` что-то не выходит - можно попытаться использовать задачи:

```
Task.WaitAll(list.Select((item, index) => Task.StartNew(() => {
    /** тут код **/

    /* здесь item - элемент списка, index - номер элемента в списке */
})));
```

Но если и с задачами не выйдет - проверьте загруженность процессора. SSH же использует криптографию, а криптография процессор неплохо нагружает...

Answer (score 0):

Как указывает название опции `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` -- это *максимальное* количество потоков. Опция является скорее подсказкой, нежели приказом. Фактическое же количество потоков подбирается библиотекой, исходя из количества ядер и загруженности системы. Стоит отметить, что потоки занимают память, а на переключение между ними требуется время. Оптимальное количество потоков в системе на самом деле равно количеству ядер -- все потоки будут заняты работой, отсутствуют траты на переключение контекста. Понятно, что в работающей ОС запущено множество потоков, поэтому библиотека оптимальный вариант -- запустить столько же потоков, сколько у вас ядер.

Если вы хотите завести фиксированное количество потоков -- воспользуйтесь тасками. Алгоритм следующий:

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = GetTasks();
int maxDegreeOfParallelism = 10;
var queue = new Queue<Task>(maxDegreeOfParallelism);

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    queue.Enqueue(task);
    if (queue.Count >= maxDegreeOfParallelism)
    {
         await queue.Dequeue();
    }
}

while (queue.Count > 0)
{
    await queue.Dequeue();
}
```

Однако нужно тестировать: может случиться, что принудительный запуск 10 тасков (потоков) будет работать медленнее, чем 3 потока. Особенно в вашем случае, когда SSH использует процессор и сеть, а код у вас синхронный.

Если же существует асинхронная версия SshClient, и вы правильным образом напишете весь код асинхронно, то теоретически получите выигрыш даже меньшим количеством потоков, поскольку пока данные ходят по интернету, поток может не ждать их, а заняться другой работой (например, обработкой уже пришедших результатов).